# Selective images not showing up on Django app deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

I had 5 images on the team page of my project.
I updated 3 of them.

Now whenever I run the app on a localhost port, using
`python migrate.py`, all updated images on the page are shown.

As soon as I deploy the app on Heroku, 3 out of 5 images aren't updated.
They still show a previous version.

I tried deleting my browser cache, but to no avail.
I thought maybe the URLs were pointing to a wrong directory, but the updated versions of 2 images are shown.

I can't identify what the problem is.

**Project Structure -**

- reviewer/team_page.html [ Image URL - "../static/team/xyz.png" ]
- static/team/ [contains images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the following link : 
https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted,

`The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy.`

`"The filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for persistent storage of data"`

All persistent data (eg - images) need not be stored on the Heroku server, but can be uploaded on an **Amazon S3 Bucket**, and linked in the code.